# Change Order of Containers for iPad and Mobile-Tabs

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, product-page

I want to display Product-image before the main information but in iPads (and in other tabs) Main-information is displaying before product images. I try to achieve by changing order as:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" before="-" />
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" after="product.info.media"  />
```

But this is not working. This problem prevails only in mobile tabs (iPads, tabs etc) and not on other mobile-devices. how can i achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I done this by following below steps:

Edit your extended `catalog_product_view.xml` at below location , if not present then create here

```
/app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Then Add following lines of code :

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media"  before="product.info.main"/>
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main"  after="product.info.media" />
```

clean the cache etc.